# Finding Variable Name Associated With The Largest Odd Number

Tags: python, if-statement

The assignment is to print the largest odd number among 3 variables --- x, y, and z. Now my code can find the largest odd number, but how can I tell the answer is associated with which variable (x, y or z)?

```
x = 123414121
y = 148723221240982121
z = 10420116234121

numbers = [x, y, z]
oddnumbers =[]

for i in numbers:
    if (i%2!=0):
        oddnumbers.append(i)

if len(oddnumbers) == 0:
    print ("none is odd")
else:
    print("largest odd number:", max(oddnumbers))
```

Comment: What output is it expecting? Are you sure it wants variable names?

Comment: @Carcigenicate actually the assignment itself doesn't ask for variable names. But I'm curious to know how to get that :D

Comment: That would be a bit of a pain. You could maybe make use of `globals()`, or some messy `if` checks to compare each against the found max number. Normally in code, you don't care about the names of variables at runtime. That's not very useful information unless you need it for debugging, or you're doing something odd like dynamically creating variables.

Comment: If the strings `x` `y` and `z` are significant, you should be using a dictionary for your data and these would be keys. Variable names should rarely(if ever) be significant to the program.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the value correctly -- but if you want the variable name, you'll need a way to reflect and see which value corresponds to the variable name. For that you'll need an associative data structure; for example, a `dict` or a `tuple`.

Here's one way to do it (with a `dict`):

```
values = {
    'x': 123414121,
    'y': 148723221240982121,
    'z': 10420116234121,
    }

def is_odd(value):
    return ((value % 2) != 0)

odd_values = [v for k,v in values.items() if is_odd(v)]
max_odd_value = max(odd_values)
max_odd_value_name = [k for k,v in values.items() if v == max_odd_value][0]
```

Result:

```
>>> max_odd_value_name
'y'
```

Comment: I think we could also use: `def is_odd(value): return (value & 1) == 1;` instead.

Comment: @F.Müller The `== 1` is redundant. `return value & 1` should be fine since non-zero values are truthy.